# Dimension de la salida de una convolución

Tags: redes-neuronales

Tengo una duda sobre la dimensión de la salida en una capa de una CNN. En la imágen se ve las dimensiones de entrada y de salida en la segunda capa de una CNN. Si la entrada de la convolución son 32 matrices de tamaño 14x14 y le aplicamos 64 kernels ¿No deberíamos obtener como salida 64*32 matrices detamaño 14x14?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás la comunidad de data science sea un lugar más adecuado para este tipo de preguntas -> https://datascience.stackexchange.com/